# get python pandas to_dict with orient='records' but without float cast

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one col int one col floats:

```
df
#    a      b
# 0  3  42.00
# 1  2   3.14

df.dtypes
# a      int64
# b    float64
# dtype: object
```

I want a list of dicts like the one provide by `df.to_dict(orient='records')`

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
[{'a': 3.0, 'b': 42.0}, {'a': 2.0, 'b': 3.1400000000000001}]
```

But with `a` as `int`, not casted as float

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12859 `[x._asdict() for x in df.itertuples()]` is suggested in that page as a workaround.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently (as of Pandas version 0.18), `df.to_dict('records')` accesses the NumPy array `df.values`. This property upcasts the dtype of the `int` column to `float` so that the array can have a single common dtype. After this point there is no hope of returning the desired result -- all the ints have been converted to floats.

So instead, building on [ayhan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897527/get-python-pandas-to-dict-with-orient-records-but-without-float-cast#comment63248425_37897527) and [Tom Augspurger's suggestion](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12859#issuecomment-208319535) you could use a list and dict comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,2], 'b':[42.0,3.14]})
result = [{col:getattr(row, col) for col in df} for row in df.itertuples()]
print(result)
# [{'a': 3, 'b': 42.0}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3.1400000000000001}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another horrible workaround is to (temporarily) add a non-numeric column, e.g. starting with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.4], [3, 4.0]], columns='a b'.split())
```

then `df.to_dict(orient='record')` promotes to floats, but if you do:

```
df['foo'] = 'bar'
[{k: v for (k, v) in row.items() if k != 'foo'} for row in df.to_dict(orient='record')]
```

you preserve the original types.  I notice that `df.reindex()` behaves similarly, as explained in the [Pandas gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/gotchas.html#gotchas) but you can't workaround unless you fill with non-nil values, e.g. `fill_value=0`